# Java (Eclipse): cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing some homework and I'm getting the "cannot be resolved to a type" error on **computeInvoice** in my TestInvoice.java. I know that renaming all instances of "**computeInvoice**" to "**Invoicing**" would solve the problem, but we were specifically instructed to use "**computeInvoice**" as the method name, hence causing this error.

Here is the code:

```
    //Invoicing.java

    public class Invoicing {

    private double bookPrice;
    private int bookQuantity;
    private double couponValue;
    private double grandTotal;

    public double getGrandTotal() {
        return grandTotal;
    }

    public void setGrandTotal(double grandTotal) {
        this.grandTotal = grandTotal;
    }

    public double getBookPrice() {
        return bookPrice;
    }

    public void setBookPrice(double bookPrice) {
        this.bookPrice = bookPrice;
    }

    public int getBookQuantity() {
        return bookQuantity;
    }

    public void setBookQuantity(int bookQuantity) {
        this.bookQuantity = bookQuantity;
    }

    public double getCouponValue() {
        return couponValue;
    }

    public void setCouponValue(double couponValue) {
        this.couponValue = couponValue;
    }




    public void computeInvoice(double bookPrice)
    {
        this.bookPrice = bookPrice;
        bookQuantity = 1;
        couponValue = 0;
        grandTotal = bookPrice*1.08;
    }

    public void computeInvoice(double bookPrice, int bookQuantity)
    {
        this.bookPrice = bookPrice;
        this.bookQuantity = bookQuantity;
        couponValue = 0;
        grandTotal = (bookPrice*bookQuantity)*1.08;
    }

    public void computeInvoice(double bookPrice, int bookQuantity, double couponValue)
    {
        this.bookPrice = bookPrice;
        this.bookQuantity = bookQuantity;
        this.couponValue = couponValue;
        grandTotal = ((bookPrice*bookQuantity) - couponValue)*1.08;
    }

    public void grandTotal()
    {
        System.out.println("Total: $" + grandTotal);
    }

}
```

And here's the driver class:

```
//TestInvoice.java

public class TestInvoice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Invoicing oneBook = new computeInvoice(24.95);
        Invoicing twoBook = new computeInvoice(17.50, 4);
        Invoicing threeBook = new computeInvoice(10.00, 6, 20.00);

        oneBook.grandTotal();
        twoBook.grandTotal();
        threeBook.grandTotal();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to get around the naming issue? With the way the homework instructions seem to be, it seems like there's probably a method of creating an overloaded method under a name different from the that of the class's?

Answer (score 2):

> cannot be resolved to a type" error on computeInvoice

Since `computeInvoice()` is mothod in `Invoicing` class. So first you need instance of `Invoicing` class and call `computeInvoice()` flavours on that object.

```
    Invoicing invoice =new Invoicing();
    invoice.computeInvoice(24.95);
    invoice.computeInvoice(17.50, 4);
    invoice.computeInvoice(10.00, 6, 20.00);

    invoice.grandTotal();
    invoice.grandTotal();
    invoice.grandTotal();
```

Comment: He should be making the field assignments from a constructor ideally, or just change the method into `static`.  Really, the code has too many problems to merit answering IMO.

Comment: @Satya I tried replacing the code with what you suggested and now I'm getting "the method is undefined".

Comment: may be you are changing method type to `static`. otherwise it will works.

Comment: Still not working for me. Still appreciate you trying though :)

Comment: may be some `import` is missing if two these two classes are indifferent packages. just check carefully.

Comment: Is there something I could do differently from the beginning?